# Strange calculation of 100%

Tags: css, margins

I have the following structure and layout:

> [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/omanot/3)

**Question:**
Why is `margin-top: 6%` calculated as more pixels for `div#content` than for `div#header`?

**Note:** The parent of both elements has `height: 100%` set, just as `div#top-container` has.

 I have a strong feeling this has something to do with the fact that `div#header` and `div#content` is floated, but I really can't figure out why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the **width** of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

Comment: That was odd. I've always thought `top` and `bottom` margins where calculated from the vertical height. Anyway, marking as the answer since **you used \*\* on `width`**

Answer (score 0):

read specs carefully.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.